# Automatic turn off of water pump as water tank overflows (Manual turn on is needed)

Tags: electrical, water, pump, water-tank, overflow

I want to design a system that automatically turns off a water pump when the water tank is full.
**Some background and details:**
1- The pump is connected to main water supply.
2- The pump should turn on with a switch (manual input) and it should stop when water tank overflows.
3- It should not turn on automatically as the water level goes down.
4- The main water supply is irregular. Therefore, I prefer to have a manual turn on.

Can some one please suggest a circuit/design to achieve this?

Comment: What specifically are you asking? Have you attempted to design this circuit yourself?

Comment: Thanks. I am asking for potential ideas for the circuit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about designing a circuit, not home improvement.

Comment: A float switch will handle the shut off, some sump controllers may allow you to set this up without altering. This looks like a winner: https://www.plumbingsupply.com/emergency-high-water-shut-off-switch.html  You can probably do it cheaper yourself with a microprocessor, sensor, and relay.

Comment: @HartCO Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is out there, in the form of residential effluence treatment (septic).

It utilizes float switches and a small analog or digital controller that automates exactly what your looking for.

Research "septic pump tank design". You're looking for a system with 3 or 4 float switches installed. Parts for these systems are available all over the world.